# How to Register Multiple Host Names for Server in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a Windows 2008 server in our corp network which hosts multiple IIS applications.  I want to have users access it via multiple names, e.g. http://app1, http://app2.  How do I register multiple host names in AD to point to this server?  Can I do this myself on the server, or do I need to have a domain admin do this?

Answer (score 1):

IIS supports Named Virtual Hosts, just like Apache, so long as you don't require SSL for those sites. That way you can use a single IP for everything. For your SSL sites you'll need an IP for each, but IIS can handle that just as well.

As for hostnames, there is not a whole lot you can do from a pure developer standpoint to register new AD names. However, it is possible to ask your MS DNS administrators to register the names in the AD DNS domain. We've do this for our WebDevs all the time.